# Typography for arrow-linked list on several lines

Tags: icons, typography

I’m working on a text-based UI (no graphics other than text) which lists food items ordered one after the other. These food items are connected one another with an arrow symbol. For example:

“Food A --> Food B --> Food C --> Food D” and so on. The list takes the number of lines necessary to display all the content.

The question is when I reach the end of a line, should I display the arrow leading to the next item in the current line, or on the next line ? Is there is a typographical convention for this ?

I mean, either:
“Food A --> Food B --> Food C **-->**

Food D”

Or:
“Food A --> Food B --> Food C

**-->** Food D”

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

No typographical knowledge but...

Any possibility of repeating the arrow?

```
Food A --> Food B --> Food C -->

--> Food D
```

That way at a glance you know Food C is not the end of the chain and Food D is not the start of a new chain

Comment: Great, it's a pragmatic solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I also agree with the above provided answer, but you can also consider using an ellipsis (...) for the top line and the arrow on the bottom.

```
Food A --> Food B --> Food C ...
  --> Food D
```

You can also just think about having the arrow at the top, and tab the second line inward, like so:

```
Food A --> Food B --> Food C -->
  Food D --> Food E
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas ! I tested the ellipsis, but some people might interpret it as meaning that the label for the preceding item (food C in this case) is incomplete, which is not the case. And as for the 2nd suggestion, the inconvenient is that "Food D" might be interpreted as a sub-label for Food A (since it's indented jut below). So I think I'll do as the answer above suggests.